# Datamapper IS NOT NULL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datamapper

How can I write the activerecord statement,

```
Comments.where("attachment IS NOT NULL")
```

in DataMapper

ie., I want to execute `"SELECT * FROM comments WHERE attachment IS NOT NULL;` with DataMapper in rails.

Please help; I am not much familiar with DM!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using the old AR 2.3 syntax should work for you

```
Comment.all(:conditions => 'attachment IS NOT NULL')
```

Alternatively, you can use the `not` method available on symbols for DataMapper queries:

```
Comment.all(:attachment.not => nil)
```